# Google Tag shows up in Tag Manager and Analytics but not Google Ads

Tags: google-tag-manager, gtag.js

I have created a combined tag and installed it just after the  tag in my website.

The tag can be verified in Tag Manager and Analytics but Google Ads won't run because Google Ads can't detect the tag.

Anyone seen anything like this before?